# Invoke select-buffer inside the current buffer

Tags: buffers

I accidentally activate `select-buffer` inside the current buffer's working area

[image]

However, no idea how to repeat the above operation even though pressing various keys.

Cloned the configuration from doom-emacs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know much about doom-emacs. It may be `SPC ,` or `SPC <` or `b b`.

For the future issues like this when something interesting happens and you wonder what key is causing it the command `view-lossage` is very helpful:

> `C-h l` runs the command `view-lossage` (found in `global-map`), which is an
>   interactive compiled Lisp function in `help.el`.
>
> It is bound to `C-h l`, `<f1> l`, `<help> l`.
>
> Display last few input keystrokes and the commands run.